# Batch - Moving folders and contents based on name to a different drive

Tags: batch-file, move, xcopy

First post, and I have searched and tried for this but cant seem to find something like this.

Okay, so I have spent some time on this and have hit a wall.  I understand and can code this if I am moving on a single drive (with move) but as soon as I try to implement xcopy so that it will work cross drives I begin to struggle.

This is what I have so far.  This will look in the directory name for a left parenthesis and if it has it, it will try to move the directory to the other folder.  This works correctly.

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

for /d %%f in ("%C:\Testing\Folder1%\*") do (
SET "folder=%%f"
if /I NOT "!folder:(=!"=="!folder!" move "%%f" C:\Testing\Folder2
)
```

Example directory names are as follows

Vacation (2004) - Move

Florida Vacation - Dont Move

New York (2014) - Move

Exmaple Folder - Dont Move

Now when I found out move does not work for different drives (D: (source) and E: (destination)) I found out I needed to use Xcopy.  When I try to use xcopy instead of move it will never move any files or folders.

I am thinking I might have to mkdir the folder in the new location first and then move everything and delete the old one, but then I would need to substring the directory name from the full path.  I probably can do it, but want to verify with you guys before I spend another half day googling how to do it.  I have slammed my head into the wall enough for the past few days that I figured some experts could help out.

Attempt with xcopy

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

for /d %%f in ("%D:\Folder1%\*") do (
SET "folder=%%f"
if /I NOT "!folder:(=!"=="!folder!" xcopy "%%f" E:\Folder2
)
```

I appreciate any and all help you can give.

Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following, perhaps it'll work for you:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /d %%i in (C:\TEST\*(*) do (
xcopy "%%i" "D:\%%~pni" /s /i
)
pause
```

Substitute paths for your relevant directories. Good luck!

Comment: Not sure why this wont format correctly, but I end up with the same problem with xcopy that it doesnt copy.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.  Below are the results.

    C:\Testing>(xcopy "C:\Testing\Folder1\Test 2 1 (2013)"     "C:\Testing\Folder2\Testing\Folder1\Test 2 1 (2013)" /s /i )
    0 File(s) copied

    C:\Testing>(xcopy "C:\Testing\Folder1\Test2 (2003)" "C:\Testing\Folder2\Testing\Folder1\Test2 (2003)" /s /i )
0 File(s) copied

    C:\Testing>(xcopy "C:\Testing\Folder1\This is the Test (2008)" "C:\Testing\Folder2\Testing\Folder1\This is the Test (2008)" /s /i )
0 File(s) copied

Comment: Are these test folders? ...and if they are you may need the /e switch if they're empty. See [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html).

Comment: That was it.  Thank you!  It seems it is creating the testing folder inside folder2 so its path is C:\Testing\Folder2\Testing\Folder1 but I can figure that one out.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome... just in case `%%~pni` is an expansion modifier, it will expand the iteration/variable `%%I` to its path and name. You may just want the `n` expansion, and provide the path before the "\". For more info, see [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html). Good luck!